# how to obtain an element/column even when it's NA with tapply in R

Tags: r, na, tapply

I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame("y"=c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2010,2012,2010,2011,2012),"x"=c(1,2,1,1,2,2,4,4,4),"a"=c(5,3,0,2,3,0,2,3,0))



    y  x a
1 2010 1 5
2 2011 2 3
3 2012 1 0
4 2013 1 2
5 2010 2 3
6 2012 2 0
7 2010 4 2
8 2011 4 3
9 2012 4 0
```

And I want to sum 'a' for each 'y' and 'x', using:

```
sum <- tapply(df$a,list(df$y,df$x),sum)
```

That is:

```
      1  2  4
2010  5  3  2
2011 NA  3  3
2012  0  0  0
2013  2 NA NA
```

How can i obtain also the '3' column, even though I don't have the value 3 in the column x of df?
Something like this:

```
      1  2   3   4
2010  5  3  NA   2
2011 NA  3  NA   3
2012  0  0  NA   0
2013  2 NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `x` column as `factor` with `levels` that include all the values between `min` and `max` of `x` column.

```
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = seq(min(df$x), max(df$x)))
tapply(df$a,list(df$y,df$x),sum)

#      1  2  3  4
#2010  5  3 NA  2
#2011 NA  3 NA  3
#2012  0  0 NA  0
#2013  2 NA NA NA
```